# How to install python for one user on centos?

Tags: python, centos

I'm working a linux machine running CentOS. I don't have full sudo powers and theres multiple versions of python already installed on the machine and the whole thing is a bit of a mess, stuff like numpy doesn't work and I need to install modules which rely on that.

I was wondering if its possible to just install python (and hopefully R) into my own home directory or something and then install the modules I need into that directory and run what I need from there?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using virtualenv. Of course this assumes that your system already has virtualenv installed.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv

Basic usage:

```
virtualenv venv
```

That creates a directory called 'venv' at your current folder. It puts in the appropriate `python` and `pip` binaries.

To go into the virtual environment:

```
. venv/bin/activate
```

or equivalently:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

That is the key step. From then on, any packages installed using `pip` will be local to the virtualenv folder that we created above. Remember to do the above step before installing your packages and running your programs. Running `python` will also use the `python` from the virtualenv.

You should see something like:

```
(venv)[username@host]$
```

on your shell.

Install packages using pip like this:

```
pip install packagename
```

This will install packages for the virtualenv we created in the first step.

`pip` makes use of a `requirements.txt` file for specifying packages required for your python programs. If you have a `requirements.txt` file, you can use:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

to install the packages specified in that file.

For running your python program:

```
python programName
```

or use the relevant command you need. Based on my limited experience so far, I have run `gunicorn` for web applications. This will use the `python` and associated libraries from our virtualenv.

To deactivate the virtualenv, use:

```
deactivate
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

Make a directory where you install your own software:

```
mkdir -p ~/sw/src
cd ~/sw/src
```

Download and untar Python source into this directory. Configure it to install into `~/sw`, then compile (make sure all the required headers are available, notably those for SSL if you want to open HTTPS urls with `urllib2`):

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/sw
make
make install
```

Finally, set your `PATH` to include `$HOME/sw/bin` in `.bashrc` (or a similar shell startup file). Now run `python`.

R should work similarly.

Answer (score 0):

If your system has gcc installed you might consider building from sources, as explained here: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/README for Python 2.7 or here:
http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/README for Python 3.3

In this way you'll be sure to have a clean installation. It would still be a good idea to use virtualenv even with a private installation.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some additional information to previous answers.

Python 3 has its own lightweight version of virtual environment. So if you use Python 3 (either provided by your system or built on your own) you can just run:

```
python -m venv my_env
```

and this will create isolated environment in `my_env` directory.

Run `python -m venv --help` to get some help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert but I hope it helps someone.

I've followed the steps as is and I was able to install python for one single user.

http://thelazylog.com/install-python-as-local-user-on-linux/

[image]